# Update multidimensional array by id?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have a multi dimensional array like this:

```
var firstElement = $(this).first();
fielddata = {
  number: index,
  attributes: [
    { 'label_text': firstElement.text(), 
      'label_width': firstElement.width(), 
      'label_height': firstElement.height(), 
      'label_color': firstElement.css('color') 
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I change one of the values inside the attributes part but by id? so I make 'label_text' a different value?

I do not want to use the index.

Comment: What *id* are you talking about? By id, do you mean the object's key *label_text*? `fielddata.attributes[0].label_text`??

Comment: fielddata.attributes[0]['label_text'] = 'something'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have a multidimensional array. You have an object; one of its properties is an array of objects.

In this case, it looks like you want to update `label_text` in the first (and only) object in the `attributes` list. If that's correct:

```
fielddata.attributes[0].label_text = 'whatever';
```

Will work, as would:

```
fielddata.attributes[0]['label_text'] = 'whatever';
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I understand it is an object now and not an array :) Thanks